# how to display a dropdown ul two per row

Tags: html, css

I have a Nav with some unordered elements displayed horizontally and then I have a submenu from one of those elements of the nav, so far I'm displaying all the elements inline but I would like to display them side by side, just two of them per line.

How it actually looks:

[image: ACTUAL LOOK]

And how I want it to be:

[image: DESIRED STYLE]

Just two columns displaying elements side by side, aligned to left side (of 50% width each side).

But I can't get it done, here's what I got so far

HTML

```
<nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu1"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="">NEWS</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="">VIDEOS</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="">STYLE</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="">BEAUTY</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="">MOMS</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="">PETS</a></li>
                <li class="left"><a href="" class="news">NEWS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Content1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Content2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Content3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Content4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Content5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Content6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Content7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Content8</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </nav>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
position: absolute;
left:80px;
top:50%;
transform: translate(0%,-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(0%,-50%);
}

#menu ul {
list-style:none;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
top:50%;
}

#menu ul li {
display: inline;
position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
background-color: ;
position: relative;
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul li a.news {
color:#ec008c;
transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul li a:hover.news {
color: #fff;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
background-color: #ec008c;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid #bf1b33;
color: #fff;
}

#menu ul ul
{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
right: 0%;
margin-left:0px;
text-align: center;
width: 350px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-top:12px;
background-color: #243641;

}

#menu ul ul.longer {
width: 150px;
}

#menu ul ul li
{
float:none;
width:100%;
background-color: ;
}

#menu ul ul a
{
line-height: 0px;
padding:0px 5px;
width: 100%;
background-color: ;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul
{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
#menu ul ul li
{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

[See working demo here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/grxXVy)

Comment: It might not be the only solution though, nor the better one. It's just the fastest based on your current code. Have a look at the other solutions proposed by oboshto and Roy, just so you know they exist and maybe rethink the way you designed your menu.

Comment: thank you, and there's a way to approach more the elements inside that ul ul list? I mean I'm changing the padding but keep showing them with a high amount of space :(

Comment: If blocks are 50% width, they will always cover half the width of the parent block, no matter their inner padding. You can resize the `ul` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on the last `ul` and set a `flex-basis` width on the children (`li`). See my example below.

```
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#menu ul ul li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

This is all the extra code that's needed. I also fixed your code. because the `<ul>` didn't have closed tag (`</ul>`).

```css
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  background-color: ;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul li a.news {
  color: #ec008c;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu ul li a:hover.news {
  color: #fff;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #ec008c;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #bf1b33;
  color: #fff;
}

#menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  background-color: #243641;
}

#menu ul ul.longer {
  width: 150px;
}

#menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ;
}

#menu ul ul a {
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ;
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#menu ul ul li {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu1"><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="">NEWS</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="">VIDEOS</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="">STYLE</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="">BEAUTY</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="">MOMS</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="">ENTERTAINMENT</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="">PETS</a></li>
    <li class="left"><a href="" class="news">NEWS</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Content1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Content2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Content3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Content4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Content5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Content6</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Content7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Content8</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `display: inline-block;` width `width: 50%` on `#menu ul ul li` elements:

```
#menu ul ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;
right: 0%;
margin-left:0px;
text-align: center;
width: 350px;
line-height: 60px;
margin-top:12px;
background-color: #243641;
font-size: 0; /* white spaces fix */
}

#menu ul ul li {
font-size: 1rem; /* white spaces fix */
float: none;
width: 50%;
display: inline-block;
background-color: ;
}

#menu ul ul a {
display: block;
padding: 0px 5px;
width: 100%;
background-color: ;
}
```

JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jktxdnod/).

Answer (score -4):

This might be useful for your needs.

I don't know if you are using any framework or not, but this should work for you :)

http://alijafarian.com/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/

Comment: this is not an answer just a link